# JavaScript with JQUERY (convert)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help guys. My teacher is teaching us Java Script, and He gave for us a exercise to use JQuery in this Script. But I' don't know do it, because he gave only 1 lesson about it, i tried since yesterday, but I didn't have sucess. Please help me. I so sorry about my English but i'm from Brazil, so I don't write English very well.

This is the Script that I need to use JQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function geraAleatorio() {
                var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
                var naipe = [];
                naipe[0] = "&clubs;";
                naipe[1] = "&hearts;";
                naipe[2] = "&spades;";
                naipe[3] = "&diams;";

                var valores = [];
                valores[0] = "K";
                valores[1] = "A";
                valores[2] = "2";
                valores[3] = "3";
                valores[4] = "4";
                valores[5] = "5";
                valores[6] = "6";
                valores[7] = "7";
                valores[8] = "8";
                valores[9] = "9";
                valores[10] = "10";
                valores[11] = "Q";
                valores[12] = "J";

                var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 52) + 1);
                var peso = num % 13; 
                var x = Math.floor(num / 13);
                var r = naipe[x];

                if (num == 13) { 
                    peso = 0; 
                    x = 0;
                } else if (num == 26) {
                    peso = 0;
                    x = 1;
                } else if (num == 39) {
                    peso = 0;
                    x = 2;
                } else if (num == 52) {
                    peso = 0;
                    x = 3;
                }
                resultado.innerHTML = num + "<br>" + valores[peso]+  "&nbsp;" + r;
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="geraAleatorio();">Gerar</button>
        <p id="resultado"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked it into jQuery.  Hopefully it will be enough for your teacher.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(e){ //Trigger button click
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default button behavior
    var naipe = ["&clubs;","&hearts;","&spades;","&diams;"];
    var valores = ["K","A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Q","J"];
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 52) + 1);
    var peso = num % 13; 
    var x = Math.floor(num / 13);
    var r = naipe[x];
     if (num == 13) { 
         peso = 0; 
         x = 0;
     } else if (num == 26) {
         peso = 0;
         x = 1;
     } else if (num == 39) {
         peso = 0;
         x = 2;
     } else if (num == 52) {
         peso = 0;
         x = 3;
     }
     
$("#resultado")
.empty() //empty resultado pargraph
.html( num + "<br>" + valores[peso]+  "&nbsp;" + r); //fill resultado paragraph

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Gerar</button>
        <p id="resultado"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, You helped me a lot!

```js
$('button').on('click',function(e){ //Trigger button click
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default button behavior
    var naipe = ["&clubs;","&hearts;","&spades;","&diams;"];
    var valores = ["K","A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Q","J"];
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 52) + 1);
    var peso = num % 13; 
    var x = Math.floor(num / 13);
    var r = naipe[x];
     if (num == 13) { 
         peso = 0; 
         x = 0;
     } else if (num == 26) {
         peso = 0;
         x = 1;
     } else if (num == 39) {
         peso = 0;
         x = 2;
     } else if (num == 52) {
         peso = 0;
         x = 3;
     }
     
$("#resultado")
.empty() //empty resultado pargraph
.html( num + "<br>" + valores[peso]+  "&nbsp;" + r); //fill resultado paragraph

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Gerar</button>
        <p id="resultado"></p>
```